# Why does my string function return a clojure.lang.LazySeq@xxxxxx?

Tags: clojure

I've defined the following 3 functions using the leiningen REPL:

`(defn rand-int-range [floor ceiling] (+ floor (rand-int (- ceiling floor))))`

```
(defn mutate-index
  "mutates one index in an array of char and returns the new mutated array"
  [source idx]
  (map
    #(if (= %1 idx)
       (char (+ (int %2) (rand-int-range -3 3)))
       %2)
    (iterate inc 0)
    source))

(defn mutate-string
  [source]
  (str
    (mutate-index
      (.toCharArray source)
      (rand-int (alength (.toCharArray source))))))
```

When I run `(mutate-string "hello")`, instead of the REPL printing out the mutated string, it is printing out clojure.lang.LazySeq@xxxxxx  where the 'xxxxx' is a random sequence of numbers and letters.  I would expect it to instead print something like "hellm"  Is this really giving me a string back like I think?  If it is, how can I get the REPL to show me that string?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1) To convert a sequence of characters (which is what `mutate-index` returns) to a string, use `apply str` rather than just `str`. The latter operates on objects, not sequences.

```
(str [\a \b \c])
=> "[\\a \\b \\c]"

(apply str [\a \b \c])
=> "abc"
```

2) Strings are seqable, meaning you can use sequence functions like `map` and `filter` on them directly without stuff like `.toCharArray`.

3) Consider using `map-indexed` or `StringBuilder` to accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
(apply str (map-indexed (fn [i c] (if (= 3 i) \X c)) "foobar"))
=> "fooXar"

(str (doto (StringBuilder. "foobar") (.setCharAt 3 \X)))
=> "fooXar"
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, #1 above answered my question.  I'm also going to look into #2 and #3 as they seem to be good advice.  Obviously I'm a clojure noob, so thanks.

Answer (score 8):

That happens, because the map function returns a lazy sequence, which string reprsentation is just the class name and a hash (clojure.lang.LazySeq@xxxxxx).

In order to get the original working you need to first to get the lazy sequence evaluated. By using the (apply str ...) like Justin adviced that should happen and you should get the correct result.

Otherwise normally if you see similar problems due to not evaluating a lazy sequence you should try out function doall, which forces the evalutation of a lazy sequence

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I want to get the string value of a lazy sequence I use `clojure.core/pr-str`:

```
user=> (clojure.tools.logging/infof "This is a lazy seq [%s]" (take 5 (range 100)))
INFO  user - This is a lazy seq [clojure.lang.LazySeq@1b554e1]
nil
user=> (clojure.tools.logging/infof "This is a lazy seq [%s]" (pr-str (take 5 (range 100))))
INFO  user - This is a lazy seq [(0 1 2 3 4)]
nil
```

Comment: Grrr.  This doesn't add up (but I've seen it work).  The docs for (pr-str) say it "pr to a string, returning it" and the docs for (pr) say "Prints the object(s) to the output stream that is the current value of *out*..." but I don't want it to go to *out*, I just want the lazy-seq fully realized.  Methinks LazySeq may be not as "Simple" as it is advertised.