# Realizing a Clojure lazy sequence (string) in the REPL

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

I'm trying to realize a lazy sequence (which should generate a single string) in the REPL, with no luck. The original code works fine:

```
(def word_list ["alpha" "beta" "gamma" "beta" "alpha" "alpha" "beta" "beta" "beta"])
(def word_string (reduce str (interpose " " word_list))); 
word_string ; "alpha beta gamma beta alpha alpha beta beta beta"
```

But not wanting to leave well enough alone, I wondered what else would work, and tried removing the `reduce`, thinking that `str` might have the same effect. It did not...

```
(def word_string (str (interpose " " word_list)))
word_string ; "clojure.lang.LazySeq@304a9790"
```

I tried the obvious, using `reduce` again, but that didn't work either. There's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641626/how-to-convert-lazy-sequence-to-non-lazy-in-clojure) about realizing lazy sequences that seemed promising, but nothing I tried worked:

```
(reduce str word_string)   ; "clojure.lang.LazySeq@304a9790"
(apply str word_string)    ; "clojure.lang.LazySeq@304a9790"
(println word_string)      ; "clojure.lang.LazySeq@304a9790"
(apply list word_string)   ; [\c \l \o \j \u \r \e \. \l \a \n \g \. \L \a \z \y...]
(vec word_string)          ; [\c \l \o \j \u \r \e \. \l \a \n \g \. \L \a \z \y...]
(apply list word_string)   ; (\c \l \o \j \u \r \e \. \l \a \n \g \. \L \a \z \y...)
(take 100 word_string)     ; (\c \l \o \j \u \r \e \. \l \a \n \g \. \L \a \z \y...)
```

The fact that some of the variations, gave me the *characters* in "clojure.lang.LazySeq" also worries me - did I somehow lose the actual string value, and my reference just has the value "clojure.lang.LazySeq"? If not, how do I actually realize the value?

To clarify: given that `word_string` is assigned to a lazy sequence, how would I realize it? Something like `(realize word_string)`, say, if that existed.

**Update**: based on the accepted Answer and how `str` works, it turns out that I *can* get the actual sequence value, not just its name:

```
(reduce str "" word_string) ; "alpha beta gamma beta alpha alpha beta beta beta"
```

Yes, this is terrible code. :) I was just trying to understand what was going on, why it was breaking, and whether the actual value was still *there* or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is:

```
(def word_string (apply str (interpose " " word_list)))
```

Look at the documentation of `str`:

> With no args, returns the empty string. With one arg x, returns
>     x.toString().  (str nil) returns the empty string. With more than
>     one arg, returns the concatenation of the str values of the args.

So you're calling `.toString` on the sequence, which generates that representation instead of applying `str` to the elements of the sequence as arguments.

BTW, the more idiomatic way of doing what you want is:

```
(clojure.string/join " " word_list)
```

Also, a string is not a lazy sequence. `interpose` returns a lazy sequence, and you're calling `.toString` on that.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear on my question - I was able to assign a fully-realized string to `word_string` using `reduce`, although `apply` might be better. But given that `word_string` _was_ assigned to a lazy sequence, how do I realize it? What operation would I apply to `word_string`, like `(realize word_string)`?

Comment: I think you're confused: the second assignment of word_string is not to a lazy sequence; it's to a string that results of calling .toString on a lazy sequence. The string representation of a lazy sequence is not very useful and is not what you want. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946219/why-does-my-string-function-return-a-clojure-lang-lazyseqxxxxxx

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely confused. :) There's a lot of weird, err, non-intuitive aspects to Clojure, lazy sequences, etc, that I'm still working on understanding. However, I think I see what happened in this case, _str_ isn't doing what I originally thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything special to realize a lazy seq in clojure, you just use it in any place that a seq is expected.

```
user=> (def word-list ["alpha" "beta" "gamma" "beta" "alpha" "alpha" "beta" "beta" "beta"])
#'user/word-list
user=> (def should-be-a-seq (interpose " " word_list))
#'user/should-be-a-seq
user=> (class should-be-a-seq)
clojure.lang.LazySeq
```

So we have a seq, if I use it in any case that would go through all of the values in the seq, it will end up fully realized.  e.g.

```
user=> (seq should-be-a-seq)
("alpha" " " "beta" " " "gamma" " " "beta" " " "alpha" " " "alpha" " " "beta" " " "beta" " " "beta")
```

It's still a seq though, in fact it's still the same object that it was before.

```
user=> (str should-be-a-seq)
"clojure.lang.LazySeq@304a9790"
```

As Diego Basch mentioned, calling str on something is just like calling .toString, which for the LazySeq method is apparently just the default .toString that is inherited from Object.

Since it's a seq, you can use it like any seq, whether it's been fully realized previously or not. e.g.

```
user=> (apply str should-be-a-seq)
"alpha beta gamma beta alpha alpha beta beta beta"
user=> (reduce str should-be-a-seq)
"alpha beta gamma beta alpha alpha beta beta beta"
user=> (str/join should-be-a-seq)
"alpha beta gamma beta alpha alpha beta beta beta"
user=> (str/join (map #(.toUpperCase %) should-be-a-seq))
"ALPHA BETA GAMMA BETA ALPHA ALPHA BETA BETA BETA"
```

Comment: If you use a `str`, as I did, though `(def should-be-a-seq (str (interpose " " word_list)))`, it behaves differently. Whether I _should_ be using `str` is certainly a valid question, but I'm trying to understand what was assigned to `(def word_string (str (interpose " " word_list)))`, and how to manipulate it.

Comment: @JohnC `str` returns a string. It's just not the string you want in this case.